# How can I send server data to google-analytics by measurement protocol with curl command?

Tags: curl, google-analytics, measurement-protocol

Hi I want to send a server side data to GA  , try with the following curl command :

```
curl -s -H 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/77.0.3865.90 Safari/5
37.36' -q https://www.google-analytics.com/debug/collect -d "tid=UA-163805356-1" -d "t=event" -d "ec=category" -d "ea=anotherTestAction" -d "v=1" -d "cid=18" -d "z=1"
```

the response is following

```
{
  "hitParsingResult": [ {
    "valid": true,
    "parserMessage": [ ],
    "hit": "/debug/collect?tid=UA-1xxxxx-1\u0026t=event\u0026ec=category\u0026ea=anotherTestAction\u0026v=1\u0026cid=18\u0026z=1"
  } ],
  "parserMessage": [ {
    "messageType": "INFO",
    "description": "Found 1 hit in the request."
  } ]
}
```

It does not show up in realtime dashboard, but the same data send by Hit Builder works. I disabled the exclude for bot select.

Comment: I found send to  "https://www.google-analytics.com/debug/collect"  will not displayed i n dash board , but send to collection also not work . curl -s -H 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/77.0.3865.90 Safari/5 37.36' -q https://www.google-analytics.com/collect -d "tid=UA-163805356-1" -d "t=event" -d "ec=category" -d "ea=anotherTestAction" -d "v=1" -d "cid=18" -d "z=1"

Comment: My question is is that possible to send server side (from my vmware server ) data to GA by curl command

Comment: if it possible , any configration required at GA ?

Comment: and the data send to GA by measurement protocol  can displayed in real time?

Answer (score 0):

> https://www.google-analytics.com/debug/collect

The debug endpoint only sends debug information it doesn't send the data to Google analytics. It just checks that its valid.

> https://www.google-analytics.com/collect

If you want the hits recorded.